# Changing SqlConnection timeout at runtime

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Is it possible to change the database connection timeout at runtime?  As far as I know the only way is to modify the connection string, and then create a new connection instance with the modified connection string (replacing the timeout attribute of the string).

```
<add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQL2016;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=DbUser;Password=DbPassword;Connection Timeout=6" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Some methods on a service may need to be super fast to fail when trying to connect across the internet to a database, and others can have more grace periods.

Is there a cleaner way to modify the connection time (as the database is on an internet resource)?

Note:  Only interested in varying the database connection time at runtime, am aware of and not interested in changing the command execution time.

Kind regards,

Stefan

**UPDATE**

The answer provided by styx and Zohar Peled is more what I am after, and in particular making use of the [SqlConnectiongStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class to modify connection timeout before creating an instance of a connection at runtime.

[image]

Comment: There `SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout` property.

Comment: The *connection* timeout is how long you wait trying to connect to a server. If a *command* takes too long, you want to change the *CommandTimeout* of the command.

Comment: You should also consider creating a SQL Server Agent job to run recurrent long running commands

Comment: SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout is read only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also alter the `connstring` itself (might be a little overkill)

```
        string constring = "Data Source=.\\SQL2016;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=DbUser;Password=DbPassword;Connection Timeout=6\" providerName=\"System.Data.SqlClient";
        int index = constring.IndexOf("Connection Timeout=");
        var oldTimeOut = new String(constring.Substring(index).Split('=')[1].Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());            
        constring = constring.Replace("Connection Timeout="+oldTimeOut, "Connection Timeout=" + newTimeOut);
```

Comment: If you want to change something in the connection string, an easier way is to create a new instance of [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) based on the current connection string, modify whatever property you want, and use it's `ConnectionString` property as the new connection string for the `SqlConnection` instance.

Comment: @ZoharPeled great answer

Comment: The SqlConnectionStringBuilder is more what I am after, thanks

Comment: @StefanZvonar you should rather write an aceppt your own appraoch instead of accepting this one

Answer (score 5):

> Some methods on a service may need to be super fast to fail, and others can have more grace periods.

I assume you want to change the [CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) which is the time a query takes to run.

The `ConnectionTimeout` is the time, your application takes to establish the connection to the sql server. And this time is **equal** for each method / call / query.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM FOO", sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 60; //seconds here!
```

Comment: Sorry, am interested in varying the connection time out. Understand the command timeout, but want to vary the connection timeout depending on certain situations.

Comment: I understand how the question may have been misleading, have modified question to make the intention more clearer.